# Convert linkage matrix to adjacency matrix

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

given: a linkage matrix (e.g. single link) from a hierarchical clustering
wanted: an adjacency matrix from that linkage matrix

How is in python (e.g. networkx or any other library or approach) this goal achieved? Since I do not think that I am the first one stumbling upon this issue, my hope is that there is some recipe / library function for it

Answer (score 0):

Networkx has [nx.to_pandas_adjacency](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency.html?highlight=to_pandas_adjacency#networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency) function that returns pandas dataframe with adjacency matrix for a given graph. You should create a networkx graph from the list of links and then convert it to an adjacency matrix:

```
import networkx as nx

links = [
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 3),
    (4, 5),
    (1, 5)
]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(links)
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G)
```

> ```
>     1       2       3       4       5
> 1   0.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
> 2   1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
> 3   1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
> 4   1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
> 5   1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
> ```